# REST: Using a second service to finally answer a request?

Tags: java, rest, http

Having two independent REST (micro) services where one service borrows functionality of the second to transparently answering a resource request, what are the standards / specs in place?

Example:

```
Service Addresses: 
    - /addresses/id -> {address-json for given id}
Service Persons: 
    - /persons/id -> {person small description}
    - /persons/id/homeAddress -> {address-json for persons home address or 404}
```

Implementing the persons/id/homeAddress functionality looks like:

```
homeAddress(int personId) {
    Person person = getPerson(personId);
    Optional<AddressReference> addressReference = person.getHomeAddress();
    if(addressReference.isPresent())
       return get("/addresses/" + addressReference.get());
    else
       throw new NotFoundException();
}
```

Any standard or practical advice, how to best handle different HTTP response codes of the get(...) part?

[Update]

Both services are totally independent. Actually Addresses might be a service being used in total isolation allowing to manage all different address entities in existence including shipping addresses etc. They are referenced by different datasets stored in different databases and might evolve independently.

The goal is to integrate a kind of logical reuse of functionality of a distinct second service to realize the processing of a request. One might see it even as a workflow of requests being transparent to the original client.